# how to submit drop down value after click of button

Tags: javascript, html

below coding works fine

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="menu" id="menu">
<option value="http://www.google.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.facebook.com">CNN</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to add a button next to drop down which should allow link to work after clicking the button.

Comment: So, what are you trying to do? Right now, a new window opens right after changing the selected item. Is that functionality supposed to stay? What exactly is supposed to happen with the button is clicked?

Comment: I'm not sure i got it: You want first to select one item and them when you click on another button it will go to the selected url ? Also you should come with an [mcve](/help/mcve) of your issue, not only the code that works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```js
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu');
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
 
// Set up a click event handling function for the button 
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Confirmation of action for testing
  console.log("Navigating to:" + urlmenu.value);
  
  // Open new window with correct URL
  window.open( urlmenu.value );
});
```

```html
<select name="menu" id="menu">
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="menu" id="menu">
<option value="http://www.google.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.facebook.com">CNN</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="CLICK ME" onClick="Clicked();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Clicked() {
      var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );
      window.open( urlmenu.options[ urlmenu.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, If I changed your code too much...